# Terraform adding additional machines to aws vs appending

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I've written a python script to allow users log into a box, add their access/secret key and then deploy an instance into an vpc. It also does a couple of other things like pre-tagging instances etc etc.

My problem is this:

1. User-A logs in, enters his information and script deploys the
   instance
2. User-B logs in, enters his information .. instead of deploying a new instance its modifying User-A's instance.

I know this is a simple problem but im very new to terra form.

Here is the current TF file:

```
  1 provider "aws" {
  2   #access_key = "${var.access_key}"
  3   #secret_key = "${var.secret_key}"
  4   region     = "${var.region}"
  5 }
  6
  7
  8 resource "aws_instance" "User-A" {
  9   ami = "${lookup(var.amis, var.region)}"
 10   instance_type = "t2.micro"
 11   subnet_id ="subnet-12688d4a"
 12
 13
 14    tags {
 15          Name = “user-A box”
 16          multicast = “group,172.16.0.10"
 17          owner = “USER-A”
 18        }
 19
 20
 21    provisioner "local-exec" {
 22        command = "echo ${aws_instance.labMain.public_ip} > pubip.txt"
 23        }
 24 }
 25
 26 resource "aws_eip" "ip" {
 27    instance = "${aws_instance.labMain.id}"
 28    }
 29
 30
 31 output "Your Instance's pubic ip is" {
 32    value  = "${aws_eip.ip.public_ip}"
 33    }
```

Basically

1. I don't know where to have User-B append the tf file.
2. Do I just reproduce the code, ie Line 8-33 , again in line 34 but
   for User-B's information?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I see how this works now.

To make multiple unique instances you just need to declare unique resources names. For example:

Compacted the code above this is 1 instance called "vlslabMain"

```
8 resource "aws_instance" "User-A" { stuff }
26 resource "aws_eip" "ip" { stuff }
```

To make additional instances you just have to define a new resource name

```
#instance1
resource "aws_instance" "User-A" { stuff }
resource "aws_eip" "ip-User-A" { stuff }

#instance2
resource "aws_instance" "User-B" { stuff }
resource "aws_eip" "ip User-B" { stuff }
```